# Generating all numbers between 2 dates saved as [day, hour]

Tags: javascript

I am given 2 dates, which is saved as 2 numbers [hour, weekday], where hour can be 0-23 and weekday can be 1-7. I am then trying to generate all the hours inbetween, such that e.g. [13, 2] and [2, 3] would generate:

```
[13,2]
[14,2]
[15,2]
...
[0,3]
[1,3]
[2,3]
```

I also have the 2 dates as datetimes, but I don't know if it is easier to use those. There is never more than a few days between the 2 dates, and they never cross the end of the week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `next` date function that relies on `%` to select the next hour and day, and then you can generate all dates within a range with a simple `while` loop:

```js
function next([hour, day]) {
  let nextHour = (hour + 1) % 24;
  let nextDay = nextHour === 0 ? (day % 7) + 1 : day;
  return [nextHour, nextDay];
}

function range([h1, d1], [h2, d2]) {
  let res = [], ch = h1, cd = d1;
  while (ch !== h2 || cd !== d2) {
    res.push([ch, cd]);
    [ch, cd] = next([ch, cd]);
  }
  res.push([ch, cd]);
  return res;
}

console.log(range([13, 2], [2, 3]));
console.log(range([13, 7], [10, 2]));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably easier to use two `Date` objects.
Something like:

```js
var date1 = new Date(2018, 11, 20, 13);
var date2 = new Date(2018, 11, 21, 3);
var result = [];


while(date1.getTime() <= date2.getTime()) {
   result.push(new Date(date1.getTime()))
   date1.setHours(date1.getHours() + 1);
}

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
const getDate = (h, d) => {
  let date = new Date()
  date.setHours(h)
  date.setDate(date.getDate() - date.getDay() + d);
  return date
}
const generateRange = (s, e) => {
  let [startHour, startDay] = s, [endHour, endDay] = e, result = []
  startDate = getDate(startHour, startDay), endDate = getDate(endHour, endDay)

  while (startDate < endDate) {
    startDate.setHours(startDate.getHours() + 1)
    result.push([startDate.getHours(), startDate.getDay()])
  }
  return result
}

console.log(generateRange([13, 2], [2, 3]))
console.log(generateRange([11, 1], [3, 2]))
```

The idea is to create the 2 dates and then in the `while` loop just keep adding the hours until your start date is no longer less than the end date.